# Calling variables from SHELL and using them in Vim config (vimrc)

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, variables

**Question**

I am trying to use variables from SHELL inside my Vim configuration file, now, I have researched how to do this and asked ChatGPT about how as well. It is possibly due to the specific environment here on our campus which might cause issues.

**What I've tried**

```
let var = $var
```

---

```
let var = system('echo $var')
```

---

```
let var = system('zsh "echo $var"')
```

---

This one messes with my startup script since it runs a new instance of ZSH (so unclear if it otherwise would work, but I can probably assume it would not)

```
let var = system('zsh -i -c "echo $var"')
```

---

Here's how I have been calling it to check it's value:

```
echom "test: " . var
```

also tried:

```
echom "test: " . $var
```

---

**Context**

I run ZSH, using ohmyzsh on top of that.

I can echo the variable in shell just fine, from within a Vim buffer or terminal.

The variable itself that I am trying to call is set in my zshrc like so:

```
var="value"
export $var
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I believe the problem is `export $var` that should be `export var` instead.

Comment: @Friedrich your kind is the exact reason I am too afraid to even ask anything on any stack sites, I carefully crafted my question, making absolutely sure it was up to standard, yet, still, this... "while adding nothing", I found it relevant because in case what I was doing was correct, that could also have been the issue, but I wouldn't know what exact details to provide, just so that people could keep an open mind and ask details if that were true. It ended up being irrelevant, but I could not have known this because I did not see my simple syntax error, hence the question overlooking it.

Comment: I do think that’s a bit nitpicky @Friedrich, but the request was mostly kindly worded. Ella, I still recommend the tour and other helpful informational pages! Gracefully giving and receiving critique is hard, and I think both of you want the question to be the best it can be. The good news is that I think we’ve solved the problem? If so, I will vote-to-close this (no harm done, Ella, so please come back and ask more Vim questions when you have them!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export a variable to child process I believe you should do:

```
var="value"
export var
```

Remark if you do: `export $var` you will export the `value` variable.

Once the variable is correctly exported to child process if you start Vim you can the its value with the `$var` syntax:

```
:echo $var
:echom 'var: ' .. $var
```

Comment: Ah, lmao, just a simple syntax error, thank you kinda stranger!